# Adding additional condition to sort data with counts

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a report that currently using the below SQL query.

```
WITH T AS
(
    SELECT *, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY location) as Cnt
    FROM myTable1
)
SELECT incident_num, unit, incident_date, call_type, location
FROM T
WHERE Cnt > 4
and incident_date >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
order by location
```

This query gives me a set of data that has more than four same locations in the last 30 days. Now I need to add another condition where it will look for the location with more than four incident dates.

How do I add another condition to this query?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try the following.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, 
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY location) as Cnt,
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY incident_date) as Cnt2
FROM myTable1
)
SELECT incident_num, unit, incident_date, call_type, location
FROM T
WHERE Cnt > 4
and Cnt2 > 4
and incident_date >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
order by location
```

Comment: Hah! Nearly identical answer. You were first.